# Фиксированное меню

Tags: меню, html

Добрый день! У меня есть такая проблема не могу сообразить как сделать фиксированное меню, как тут например http://news.mail.ru. Чтобы когда продвигаемся вниз по сайту, меню висело в шапке всегда и было видимо. Как это сделать? Кто такое делал?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Плагинов по этой теме в инете достаточно. А если особых заморочек не нужно, то и [самому написать можно](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/g9u8G/) за несколько минут.

Answer (score 2):

В css стилях для вашего меню задайте [position: fixed](http://htmlbook.ru/css/position)

Comment: @alvoro, у меня еще такой вопрос, когда такое делаешь, это сразу выкидывает меню в левый верхний угол, а можно как-то задать относительные позиции, чтобы центровать например меню по горизонтали?

Comment: @IntegralAL используй css-свойства top, left, right, bottom. Они отвечают за смещение.

Comment: @IntegralAL, потому что фиксированный элемент всегда позиционируется относительно окна браузера. Используйте top: 0, для того, что прижать элемент к верней части окна и margin-left/right, для того, чтобы позиционировать элемент по координате x, если хотите, чтобы отсчет велся от текущей позиции.

Comment: @andreyqin зачем туда еще и margin-ы пихать? вот все с чистыми top-left [работает](http://jsfiddle.net/alvoro/Bg9JA/) margin все же за отступы отвечает, а top-left за смещение.

Comment: @alvoro, я же написал "фиксированный элемент всегда позиционируется относительно окна браузера". А относительно окна нам нужно позиционировать его только по координате Y.

Comment: @andreyqin Я просто предлагаю вместо margin-left/right использовать left/right и всё. Просто я нахожу, что в данном случае left/right уместней будет. top упомянул на случай, если захочется чуть вниз опустить. Мы, походу, просто не поняли друг друга))